# Android ListView and Child Views

Tags: android, listview

As part of my project in Android I need to create a list view that can contain images as child views.

If I long press on the image long press event is passed to image view and list view is not getting the long press event. How to disable long press on the child view and pass the long press on the list view??

I tried with android:longClickable="false" on all the child views but still it is not working...

Please help..

private void setChoiceModeListener(final ListView chatListView) {
    chatListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    chatListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        mode.setTitle(String.valueOf(chatListView.getCheckedItemCount()) + " Selected");
        mode.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actionbar_select, menu);
        chatListAdapter.setActionModeEnabled(true);
        mActionMode = mode;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        boolean emailEnabled = EmailUtility.isEmailEnabled(getActivity());
        menu.findItem(R.id.select_email).setVisible(emailEnabled);
        menu.findItem(R.id.select_copy).setVisible(canEnableCopyMenu());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        chatListView.clearChoices();
        chatListView.invalidateViews();
        chatListAdapter.setActionModeEnabled(false);
        mActionMode = null;
    }
});
```

}

## Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/date_separator"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/message_box_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/message_boudary_margin"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:background="@drawable/message_item_selector_left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/name_with_time_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckedTextView
                android:id="@+id/message_posted_time_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/chat_bubble_sample_message_posted_time"
                android:textColor="@color/message_item_time_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />

            <CheckedTextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/message_posted_time_textview"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_short_text"
                android:textColor="@color/message_item_profile_name_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />
        </LinearLayout >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageview_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name_with_time_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_small">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/message_content_imageview"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_attachment_thumbnail_max_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_attachment_thumbnail_max_size"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/file_thumb_any" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_content_text_icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_attachment_thumbnail_max_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_attachment_thumbnail_max_size"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/fa_desktop"
                android:textColor="@color/maria_spark"
                android:textSize="120sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_view"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/download_imageview"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_attachment_thumbnail_max_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_attachment_thumbnail_max_size"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/download_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/file_name_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageview_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_extra_large"
            android:text="@string/chat_bubble_sample_file_name"
            android:textColor="@color/message_item_file_name_color" />

        <com.util.views.CheckedLinkTextView
            android:id="@+id/message_content_textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name_with_time_layout"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/message_item_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_status_textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/chat_box"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/message_boudary_margin"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/maria_spark"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

-->

Comment: Can you show us your onclickevent?

Comment: use long press on view rather than on imagview in getview

Comment: Include your code showing how you are handling the events, and where you are setting them to the views.

Comment: try adding `android:descendantFocusability="false"` to the root of your list item view

Comment: Added android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the root view...But still child view is getting long click events first...

Comment: chatListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

                mode.setTitle(String.valueOf(chatListView.getCheckedItemCount()) + " Selected");

                mode.invalidate();

            }



But long clicking on ImageView onItemCheckedStateChanged wont get called, but long clicking on anywhere on the list view it will be called

Comment: @Jithin Include your code in the question, not here in the comments.

Comment: Included part of code in the question... download_imageview is getting long click event...Any possibilty to create a custom layout for this linear layout and pass the long click to parent??

Comment: I have the same Issue like above said, anybody solved this issue.